# Who should move forward between imam or the person with him when someone comes to the mosque

Tags: quran, hadith, salat, obligation

Assalamualaikum waramatullahi wabarakatuhu

My question is, whenever two people are praying and someone come to the mosque and wanted to join the prayer, how should move forward between the imam and the person with him?

Note that there's space for both of them to move to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When both are equally viable, the most recommended course of action is that the person praying behind the Imam should move back.

This is shown in a long hadith of Sahih Muslim:

> Jabir ibn Abdullah narrated:
>
> [...] Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) got up to observe prayer [...] I then came and stood upon the left side of Allah's Messenger (ﷺ). He caught hold of me and made me go round behind him, until he made me stand on his right side. Then Jabbar b. Sakhr came. He performed ablution and then came and stood on the left side of Allah's Messenger (ﷺ). Then Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) caught hold of our hands together, pushed us back and made us stand behind him. [...] ([Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/55/94))

For more detail, also see here: [What should be done if a third person joins two who are praying in jamaa’ah?](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/3262/what-should-be-done-if-a-third-person-joins-two-who-are-praying-in-jamaaah)